# Django model inheritance without db relationship?

Tags: django-models

Not sure how to structure this.  Model inheritance seems sensible, but it looks like Django will add a one-to-one link between the related models, which I don't need.  Here's my situation: I have two models, for a Game and a Turn within a game.  What I'd like to do is provide a "demo" version of these on my website for potential users to play around with.  I want them to function just like the real models, but to populate different tables (eg say "demo_game" and "demo_turn") so I can clean them periodically and not "pollute" the real game/turn tables.

What's the best way to structure this?  I could just copy the models to new versions, but would rather have a more elegant way to keep them in sync in case I modified one, but there is no need for any db relationship between a model and its demo version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [abstract base classes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for each type, then derive concrete children.

Comment: Wow, that was easy, and fast!  Thanks.